# Eclipse Java Android compile error

Tags: java, android

Why is this error happening?

http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4883/whyerror.png

I thought that `R` was the automatically generated class I am not supposed to touch?

thanks

//Anything above had no errors

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lovemenu, menu); //ERROR HERE
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch(item.getItemId()) 
        {

            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Have You tried clean build / restart eclipse?

Comment: Be sure you have NO xml errors then clean project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are NOT including the following import

```
import android.R;
```

and that your are including a reference to your own

```
import com.example.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete import android.R; if it is in your import statement. Eclipse will automatically insert the correct R.class file.

Note As mentioned by @codeMagic you need make sure that there is no error in your xml files